# How to improve a postgresql query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

can someone show me how to improve the below query and make it one statement instead of two statements? Thanks

```
CREATE LOCAL TEMP TABLE tmpdetail2
WITH (OIDS) 
ON COMMIT DROP as
  select d2.detailid, d2.objid, d2.p
  from _detail d2                         
  where d2.detailid in (19, 106);  

  select distinct d.detailid, d.p, d.pval, d.objid
  from _detail d 
  left join tmpdetail2 d2
    on d.objid = d2.objid
  where d2.objid is null 
    and d.p not in(select p from tmpdetail2)  
  order by p asc, d.detailid asc;
```

Comment: What's wrong with it - what do you you seek to improve? What's it supposed to do? (Sample data? explanation?). Why is the temp table created `with oids`? PostgreSQL version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [common table expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html):

```
with tmpdetail2 as (
  select d2.detailid, d2.objid, d2.p
  from _detail d2                         
  where d2.detailid in (19, 106)  
)
select distinct d.detailid, d.p, d.pval, d.objid
from _detail d 
left join tmpdetail2 d2
  on d.objid = d2.objid
where d2.objid is null 
  and d.p not in(select p from tmpdetail2)  
order by p asc, d.detailid asc;
```

Comment: thanks @a_horse, I removed the first semicolon and it worked fine.

Comment: @fs2050: thanks, that was a copy & paste error. Fixed.